# Can't download external library "androidx.test" via androidTestImplementation

Tags: java, android

My module's build.gradle is below:

[image]

I want to download the dependency package "androidx.text:core:1.2.0" with androidTestImplementation. But after sync now, I can't see the package in External Libraries folder, as shown:

[image]

However, if I use implementation or `testImplementation` instead of androidTestImplementation, it works and I can see the package be downloaded in External Libraries, as below:

[image]

This issue has puzzled me for a few days, please help.

Comment: Have you tried invalidating caches and restarting? Also use parenthesis like this: androidTestImplementation('...')

Comment: yes, i have tried both of them, but still failed

Answer (score 0):

You must activate a **Debug** build variant.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete .idea and .gradle folder in your project, then reopen the project from AndroidStudio.